# Cannot associate CarouselNavigator with CarouselPanel when CarouselPanel is a child element within CarouselItemsControl ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

i have xaml layout as shown below

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <dxca:CarouselItemsControl x:Name="carouselItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <dxca:CarouselPanel x:Name="carousel" AttractorPointIndex="2" IsRepeat="True" PathSizingMode="Proportional" FirstVisibleItemIndex="0" Height="Auto" ItemSize="180,120" IsAutoSizeItem="True" VisibleItemCount="5" ActiveItemIndex="1" AnimationTime="500" IsInvertedDirection="True" PathVisible="False">
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Canvas>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Data.Data}" Width="480" Height="320" Margin="10"/>
                                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="10"  Text="{Binding Identifier}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                </Canvas>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </dxca:CarouselItemsControl>
                    <dxca:CarouselNavigator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Carousel="< TODO : BINDING EXPRESSION TO BIND TO CarouselPanel>" Width="300" Height="40" />
                </DockPanel>
```

How do i bind the CarouselNavigator to the carousel object in the carousel property using xaml only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [CarouselItemsControl.Carousel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCarouselCarouselItemsControl_Carouseltopic) property for this purpose:

```
<dxca:CarouselNavigator Carousel="{Binding Path=Carousel, ElementName=carouselItemsControl}" />
```